# Problems at "Getting started with ANTLR" (Not able to create SpeakVisitor class)

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr, lexer

I'm currently going through this tutorial:

https://tomassetti.me/getting-started-with-antlr-in-csharp/#note1

But I've issues at the point where I want to create the `SpeakVisitor` class, in the tutorial the class is inheriting from a class called `SpeakBaseVisitor` which was generated by ANTLR itself.

So I looked through my whole solution and I couldn't find this created class...

All I got are two pretty much empty class files called `SpeakLexer` and `SpeakParser` which got created after I selected `Combined Grammar` in the "`Add → New Item`" dialog.

---

*SpeakLexer.cs*

```
namespace _006_ANTLR
{
    partial class SpeakLexer
    {
    }
}
```

*SpeakParser.cs*

```
namespace _006_ANTLR
{
    partial class SpeakParser
    {
    }
}
```

---

Do you got any idea why there is no `SpeakBaseVisitor` automatically generated in my case?

Greetings! :-)

Comment: You'd better learn from a complete sample so as to know how ANTLR works end to end, https://github.com/lextm/restructuredtext-antlr I don't think an article like that can cover all the technical details, and it is also too broad to chat on SO, as your entire code is not available.